# Route value removed but still added as query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am extending a model to include a link property. It is based on other properties within it to generate a link:

```
public partial class MyModelType
{
    public string FilterLink
    {
        get
        {
            var u = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
            var route = new RouteValueDictionary(u.RequestContext.RouteData.Values);
            route.Remove("other");
            route.Add("other", null);
            route.Add("id", this.Id);
            return u.Action("Index", "ControllerName", route);
        }
    }
}
```

The link generated is `/ControllerName/1?other=2`. If I get rid of the `route.Remove("other")` I  get the link based on the mapped route: `/ControllerName/1/2`. How can I prevent it being used as a query string parameter when it is removed from the route? The UrlHelper seems to be adding it somehow, even though it is not a route value.

Comment: What values are passed in `u.RequestContext.RouteData.Values`?

Comment: Just `other` and `id` (though there may be more). `other` may or may not be a route value. It depends on which view the model is on and the action parameters (`other` is nullable)

Answer (score 0):

Check your routing configuration.

MVCs routing will append any unkown parts of your route in that way, so as long as you define it up front it should work just fine.

You probably just have this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Try adding the `option` like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{option}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, option = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is discussed here: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html

However, the blogs proposal is convoluted compared with a simple solution in the comments: add "other = null as object" to the defaults values on your DEFAULT route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, other = null as object }
);
```